# How to run and stop the interval method in the subscribe if condition is met in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

Here I have query that how can I call a interval method in the subscribe and stop it after the condition is met

below is my code

**Main Subscribe method**

```
this.authservice.getdata().subscribe(response => {
   console.log(res)

   // Polling method
    
    SetInterval(()=>{
     this.getInterval();
   },5000)

})
```

**Interval Method:**

```
getInterval(){
  this.authservice.getIntervalData().subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp)
   this.responseStatus = resp
  })
}
```

In the response it gives 3 types of response

Proceed

Stop

Terminate

So here I need to call that getInterval() in Main subscribe method and until GetInterval gives me Proceed as response or until 1 min from polling I have set the interval running if either of this conditions are met i have to stop polling.

Note: I dont need polling for Main Subscribe method if main subscribe give response on success then only I have starte this polling

**Update:**
The below Method works but here i need 2  things

1. How can set variables and store the response in that
2. How can i set the boolean variable based on res like if the response comes

   this.content =true like wise

   because when i am trying to set the variables in switchMap it is not accepting

   this.authservice.getdata().pipe(
   switchMap(resp => timer(0, 5000).pipe(  // need to store this response in global variable so that it can be used for further
   switchMap(t => this.authservice.getIntervalData( <1st response param> ).pipe(
   map(data => [data, t]))) takeWhile(([data, t]) => data !== 'TERMINATE' && t < 12),
   map(([data, t]) => data)
   ))
   ).subscribe(data => console.log(data))

Comment: is `getIntervalData` the second api call after which you want to make another one using the result from the first?

Comment: @RafiHenig  after calling the getdata() with the result of this i will send as param for get interval method after getting the result of the getInterval method i will set the boolean values depending upon the condition

Comment: `@Madpop` please see my update

Comment: @RafiHenig One last thing   while using the interval(5000) we are calling the method .getIntervalData this is has to be stopped  if gets the response in the interval data as terminate and if it is not getting terminate then need to do interval for every 5 sec for 2 min and can we stop this interval outside of method i mean like a button click ?

Comment: `@Madpop`  please take a look at my update

Comment: can u update the condition for x !== 'TERMINATE' ||  60 *1000 either of these ?

Comment: @RafiHenig can u update the condition for x !== 'TERMINATE' || 60 *1000 either of these ?

Comment: what do you mean? what is your expected behavior?

Comment: my expected behavior is like :   we need to get the response from second method as "start" if we dont get start then the interval method has to be called untill the resp from second method has to get "start" or it has to call till max 1 min

Comment: what do you mean as start? right away?

Comment: in the second method i will get response as start,process,terminate so here when we call the first api we get a response and using that we are calling the second api we the above response are "start"  if we get start as response we no need to run timer and if we dont get the start and then we need to call the timer till we get the "start" or call inter val till 1 minute

Comment: I see, but that is the reason we have `takeUntil(timer(60 * 1000))` in place, it'll stop thee interval after one minute

Comment: but the here either x => x == 'start' || timer right

Comment: it should work as expected I wrote it in two lines but it will stop on either `takeUntil(timer(60 * 1000))` or   `takeWhile(x => x !== 'TERMINATE')` you can look at it as if `x !== 'TERMINATE' || 60 *1000 either of these `  let me know if is what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you probably want to just use operators and observables....

```
this.authservice.getdata().pipe( // get initial data
  tap(resp => this.myVariable = resp),
  switchMap(resp => timer(0, 5000).pipe( // switch to timer that emits every 5 seconds
    switchMap(t => this.authservice.getIntervalData().pipe( // swtich again to interval data
      map(data => [data, t]))) // map to response and timer value
    takeWhile(([data, t]) => data !== 'TERMINATE' && t < 12), // whatever stop condition, this says stop when the data is terminate or the timer has emitted 12 times (1 minute if emitting every 5 seconds)
    map(([data, t]) => data) // just send the data through
  ))
).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

something like that is how I would implement this.

Comment: But I'm already have subscribe method in component . In the services I'm using pipe method after that returning result to component level

Comment: And here first I need get the first getdata method success ful if that subscribe is successful then I need to call interval method

Comment: If the first subscribe is not successful then I won't call timer

Comment: you can structure the services however you want. just encapsulate this all in a service and return the observable. that's irrelevant. as for the following comments, that's how observables always work. a failure skips the rest of the stream.

Comment: U mean if first subscribe work then interval works and if first subscribe fails then interval also fails ?

Comment: the interval will get skipped if the first method errors. that's how all observables work.

Comment: the method which u posted it works and there is one thing i need to ask you

Comment: You can use a tap operator as I’ve added to my answer. Or you can send the original data along to the subscribe handler in the map operator.

Comment: can we also add variables  near i mean after the condition is met ? using tap

Comment: in short from the api call i want to use that response and store in variable and use that to send it as param for second api call and after getting response from 2nd api call i need to check the condition and if condition is met then store i will use boolean value variable

Comment: You can put tap operators where ever you like

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing it as demonstrated below:

```js
this.authservice.getdata().pipe(
  tap(x => this.globalVariable = x),
  switchMap(data => interval(5000).pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.authservice.getIntervalData(x)), //<== pass data from first subscription to second
    takeUntil(timer(60 * 1000)),
    takeWhile(x => x !== 'TERMINATE'),
    map(data2 => [data, data2]) // <= return values from both subscriptions 
  ))
```

Update:

> "stop this interval outside of method i mean like a button click"

```
clicked$ = new Subject<void>();

onclick(){
  this.clicked.next(); // on click emit value
}


this.authservice.getdata().pipe(
  tap(x => this.globalVariable = x),
  switchMap(data => interval(5000).pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.authservice.getIntervalData(x)), //<== pass data from first subscription to second
    takeUntil(timer(60 * 1000)),
    takeWhile(x => x !== 'TERMINATE'),
    map(intervalDataRes => this.condition = intervalDataRes),
    takeUntil(merge(this.clicked$, timer(2 * 60 * 1000))) // interval will stop after 2 or as soon as clicked$ emits
  ))
```

Comment: not sure I agree this is simpler, it's just using a second timer, but regardless, `timer(0, 5000)` is preferred to `interval(5000)` as `timer` will start immediately while `interval` will initially wait 5 seconds.

Comment: can i get the value of the first subscription ?

Comment: sure. you are receiving the values from both subscription as a single array [first, second],

Comment: i mean  using getData() i wil  get some values and that value i have  to sent to getIntervvaldata(resp) ?

Comment: @RafiHenig i have one last doubt

Comment: in short from the api call i want to use that response and store in variable and use that to send it as param for second api call and after getting response from 2nd api call i need to check the condition and if condition is met then store i will use boolean value variable

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `Subject` to store the global variable. This way you will avoid subscribing altogether

Below Solution is tested on stackblitz, [see this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4addj5)

```
  // Emit Once after 60 Seconds
  stopTime$ = timer(60000);

  // TerminateResponse
  terminateSubject$ = new Subject();
  terminateAction$ = this.terminateSubject$.asObservable();

  // Emits Every 5 seconds until stopTime is called
  interval$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.stopTime$),
    takeUntil(this.terminateAction$),
  );

  // Global Variable
  responseSubject$ = new Subject()
  responseAction$ = this.responseSubject$.asObservable();

  // Create Interval Observable. This will call getIntervalData until no more interval
  intervalData$ = this.interval$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.authservice.getIntervalData()),
    tap(res => this.responseSubject$.next({res, content: true})),
    tap(res => res === 'Terminate' ? this.terminateSubject$.next(true): ''),
  
  )
```

We define a variable

```
stopTime$ = timer(60000);
```

This emits once after 60000ms ie 1Min

Next we define

```
 terminateSubject$ = new Subject();
 terminateAction$ = this.terminateSubject$.asObservable();
```

We will use this observable to terminate the timer when condition is met using `takeUntil` operator and calling the `next()` function on the observable

We then define

```
interval$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.stopTime$),
    takeUntil(this.terminateAction$),
  );
```

this observable will emit with 0 delay every 5000ms until either `stopTime$` observable is called or `terminateAction$` is called

We then create a subject to store our global variables. Since observables are asynchronous, to avoid values being undefined, it would make sense to use observables to store our variables and subscribe to this variables whenever we need them

```
  responseSubject$ = new Subject()
  responseAction$ = this.responseSubject$.asObservable();
```

Finally we define our interval Data Observable

```
  intervalData$ = this.interval$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.authservice.getIntervalData()),
    tap(res => this.responseSubject$.next({res, content: true})),
    tap(res => res === 'Terminate' ? this.terminateSubject$.next(true): ''),

  )
```

`tap(res => this.responseSubject$.next({res, content: true}))` stores the global variable
`tap(res => res === 'Terminate' ? this.terminateSubject$.next(true): '')` Terminates the interval observable